# What if it exceeds array size , how to print error message? and terminate the program

Tags: c, arrays

Use a fixed length array of maximum size 50. In case the input file contains more than 50 students, print a message such as “The file contains more than 50 students!” and terminate the program.

i do not know how to add this. i've tried many ways using if/else statements but always getting segmentation 11 problems. please help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 50

// Function declarations
void printInfo();
int readresults(FILE*,int*, int*, int*);
void sort(float avgScore[], int stuID[], int totalStu);
float calcAvg (int score1, int score2);
void getInfo(float avgScore[], int totalStu, float* min, float* max, float* avg);
void writeSortedResults (FILE* AG_Sorted, float avgScore[], int stuID[], int totalStu);
void printdone();

int main (void)
{
// Local Declarations
    FILE* AG_Midterm;
    FILE* AG_Sorted;

    int score1[MAX_SIZE];
    int score2[MAX_SIZE];
    int stuID[MAX_SIZE];
    int i = 0;
    int totalStu = 0;

    float avgScore[MAX_SIZE];
    float avg;
    float min;
    float max;

// Statements
    printInfo();

    AG_Midterm = fopen("/Users/r3spectak/Desktop/AG_Midterm.txt", "r");
    if(AG_Midterm == NULL)
    {
      printf("\aError opening Results File\n");

      return 100;

    } // if open input

    if(!(AG_Sorted = fopen ("/Users/r3spectak/Desktop/AG_Sorted.txt","w")))
    {
      printf("\aError opening Average Results file\n");
      return 102;
    }// if open input
    i = 0;


    while(readresults(AG_Midterm, &stuID[i], &score1[i], &score2[i]))//Kexy
        {
          avgScore[i] = calcAvg(score1[i], score2[i]);
            i++;//Kexy
            totalStu++;//Kexy


        } //while

    sort(avgScore, stuID, totalStu);//Kexy

    getInfo( avgScore, totalStu, &min, &max, &avg );
    printf( "\nHighest Average Score: %.2f\nLowest Average Score: %.2f\nClass Average Score : %.2f\n", max, min, avg );
    printf("Total Students: %d\n", totalStu);

    writeSortedResults(AG_Sorted, avgScore, stuID, totalStu);

    printf("Total Students: %d\n", totalStu);

    fclose(AG_Midterm);
    fclose(AG_Sorted);


    printdone();
    return 0;

} // main


/*==================printInfo==================================
    Reads data from Midterm file
    Pre : Nothing
    Post: Prints introduction message
*/

void printInfo()
{
// Statements
    printf("Begin Calculation of Scores\n");
    return ;

} // printInfo


/*===================readResults==================================
    Reads data from AG_Midterm file
    Pre : AG_Midterm is an open file.
          stuid, score1 , score2
    Post: reads score1 and score2
          if data read -- returns 1
          if EOF or error--returns 0
*/

int readresults(FILE* AG_Midterm, int * stuID, int *score1, int *score2)
{
// Local Variables
    int i;
    int items;
    int ioCheck;

// Statements
    ioCheck = fscanf(AG_Midterm, "%d%d%d",stuID, score1, score2);

    if(ioCheck == EOF)

    {
        return 0;
    }

    else if(ioCheck != 3)

    {
        printf("Error reading file...\n");
        return 0;
    }

    else

        return 1;

} //readresults

/*===================sort===================================
    Sorts by selecting the largest Average score in unsorted
    portion of array and exchanging it with element at the
    beginning of the unsorted list.=
    Pre : list must contain atleast one item
    Post: list rearranged largest to smallest

*/

void sort(float avgScore[], int stuID[], int totalStu)
{
// Local Declarations
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int largest;
    int tempID;

    float temp;

    for(i = 0; i < totalStu; i++)
    {
        largest = i;
        for(j = i + 1; j < totalStu; j++)
        {
            if(avgScore[j] > avgScore[largest])
                largest = j;

        }

        temp = avgScore[i];
        tempID = stuID[i];

        avgScore[i] = avgScore[largest];
        stuID[i] = stuID[largest];

        avgScore[largest] = temp;
        stuID[largest] = tempID;
   }
} // sort


/*===================calcAvg==================================
    Determines the Average of the two midterm scores
    Pre : score1, score2
    Post: avgScore copied to addresses

*/
float calcAvg (int score1, int score2)

{
    return (score1 + score2)/2.0;
} // calcAvg


/*===================getInfo==================================
    Determines the Class Average,Lowest Average
    and Highest Average scores
    Pre : avgScore , totalStu
    Post: avg , min , max

*/
void getInfo(float avgScore[], int totalStu, float* min, float* max, float* avg)
{
   int i;
   float sum = *min = *max = avgScore[0];

   for( i = 1; i <totalStu; ++i )
   {
        sum += avgScore[i]; /* sum = sum + dAry[i] */
        if( avgScore[i] < *min ) *min = avgScore[i]; /* update ... if applies */
        if( avgScore[i] > *max ) *max = avgScore[i];
    }
        *avg = sum/totalStu;
    return;
}

/*===================writeSortedResults==================================
    Writes Average Scores after Sorting
    Pre : AG_Sorted is an open file
          avgScore
    Post: Data written to file
*/
void writeSortedResults (FILE* AG_Sorted, float avgScore[], int stuID[], int totalStu)
{
// Local Definitions
    int i;
    int line = 0;

// Statements
    for(i = 0; i < totalStu; i++)
    {
        fprintf(AG_Sorted, "%d %.2f     ", stuID[i], avgScore[i]);
        line++;

        if(line == 8)
        {
            fprintf(AG_Sorted, "\n");
            line = 0;
        }

    }

    printf("\nSuccessfully write the sorted data to the new file\n");
    return;


} // writeSortedResults

/*==================printDone==================================
    Reads data from Midterm Score File
    Pre : Nothing
    Post: Prints end message
*/
void printdone()
{
// Statements
    printf("End of Finalizing Scores.Thank you.\n");
    return;

} // printDone
```

Comment: After i++ , use if(i> MAXSIZE) printf("File size limit exceeded ")

Comment: i tried adding a if (i>50) in the main of while(readresults

Comment: after i++ still doesnt work it gives me segmentation error

Comment: @AccessDenied Your check should be `if (i == MAX_SIZE)`, since it is a zero-based array. However, even that won't work. For all you know the last read actually *was* the last one in the file. You don't know that until you try the next read and fail. Only if you try the next read and get back data do you know the file is, in fact, too large. Therefore, the read cannot be done directly into the target arrays. Intermediates must be used, and drop *those* into the target arrays only if you are still under you cap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your intent, you're not just interested in avoiding an overrun like everyone seems to be fixing; you're trying to abort outright if the input file *would* overrun, but without actually *letting* it overrun and therefore seg-fault your process. Checking for `feof()` won't do you any good since you may have a linefeed, some whitespace, almost anything in there that is *not* a regular record entry keeping `feof()` from being true.

To address your desired outcome (abort on too large a file) you can read data into local vars, and so long as you're under the size limit, drop them into your arrays *then*; not during the read. Otherwise abort.

```
int id, s1, s2;
while(readresults(AG_Midterm, &id, &s1, &s2))//Kexy
{
    // we *know* we have a valid record. make sure it fits
    //  before dropping it in, otherwise proclaim the file too
    // large and abort the whole thing.
    if (i == MAX_SIZE)
    {
        printf("Too many scores. Aborting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    stuID[i] = id;
    score1[i] = s1;
    score2[i] = s2;

    avgScore[i] = calcAvg(score1[i], score2[i]);
    i++;//Kexy
    totalStu++;//Kexy

} //while
```

Comment: its okay. thanks just checked with my prof. its okay to use exit

Comment: @KexyKathe In that case you should probably close your file stream pointers as well before that exit. Profs tend to frown on keeping those open =P. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the current amount of elements, plus the amount you're going to add, before actually adding them, to see if that amount exceeds 50.

```
if ( sizeof ( array ) + newAmount ) > MAX_SIZE ) {
   // Error.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you first read the data, then check if it exceeded your limit (even if at a glance I've not seen where you check it). Of course you must check first if you can read one more element, then read it; in the while, e.g.

```
 while(i < MAX_SIZE && readresults(AG_Midterm, &stuID[i], &score1[i], &score2[i]))
```

then you have to check why the loop ended. If the first condition is met, i == MAX_SIZE so you can check for it just after the while, e.g.

```
if (i == MAX_SIZE) 
{
   // abort with error
}
```

Now, this is not maybe the nicer way to do it, but solve your problem.

Comment: the program doesnt terminate, it stores till 50.

Comment: of course, there's no check if the loop breaks for the condition or for the end of the input

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this loop:

```
while(readresults(AG_Midterm, &stuID[i], &score1[i], &score2[i]))//Kexy
```

You are reading until the end of file, which causes `i` to become an invalid array index when the file contains more than 50 elements.

Add an additional condition to the `while` statement to check if `i` is still in range, like

```
while(i < MAX_SIZE && ...)
```

Comment: i tried that but the program still runs (it stores till 50). this is not what i want.